# How to build a tournament bracket in CSS without flexbox?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to reproduce something that looks almost like this : [link](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-uZCXZjaEvmHjLsP05mPsAU&q=coupe%20du%20monde%20resultat%20france%20australie&oq=&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-hp.1.0.35i39l8.0.0..15535...1.0..0.0.0.......0...........8.opZ-Q5ukKig#sie=lg;/m/06qjc4;2;/m/030q7;br;fp;1).

To see the behavior I will try to do, use the dev console to see how it works when you check the link bellow with a mobile view.

So my problem is : **how can I reproduce this in HTML / CSS without flexbox ?**

I can't use `flexbox` so I have trouble to make it clear in my mind.

Right now this is what I manage to do :

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  display:table;
}

.phase {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.333%;
  margin-right: -4px;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: table-cell;
  margin:auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#quartFinales {
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
#demiFinales {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
#finale {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.hasNextStep {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

.match {
  height: 80px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%; bottom: 25%; left: 100%; right: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.link:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px); left: 10px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

 <div id="quartFinales" class="phase">
    <div class="hasNextStep">
      <div class="match"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="match"></div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="hasNextStep">
      <div class="match"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="match"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="demiFinales" class="phase">
    <div class="hasNextStep">
      <div class="match"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="match"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="finale" class="phase">
    <div class="match"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

But as you can see this is not very flexible and if I don't use `position: absolute` everywhere I feel like I can't do it.

So my question is : **how can I make my HTML / CSS looks like what I want with less "pixel" positionning and more "fluid" positionning without flexbox ?**

For this competition I have to make it works with 3 "phases" (1/4, 1/2 and finale) but I might need to do the same with more (1/16 = 16 matches, 8e = 8 matches, 1/4, 1/2 and finale), so I need to find something I can re-use if possible !

I will repeat but I can't use `flexbox`, step 1 and 2 would be easier if I could !

If you have other idea to build the "link" or how to vertically center element I'm open to any suggestion.

I added the `jQuery` tag because I can use it too, so if you have a JS / jQuery solution it works for me!

Comment: Best suggestion is do a deep dive into the structure and positioning used in the example

Comment: Into the google code ? I just checked and it's flexbox...

Comment: What's with the flexbox limitation? Flexbox is the way to go...

Comment: I work on TV and we are limited by the modem...and flexbox is not supported (sad, I know)

Comment: Fot those who vote to close the question as "too broad", can I know why ? I edited my post to make it clear and I don't know what's "too broad" ? My question is just about doing a responsive tournament bracket without using flexbox (and grid) because I can't use them

Answer (score 2):

For such things only grid. The best combination is flex and grid ;)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 205px);
  align-items: center;
}

.justify-space-around {
  display: grid;
  align-content: space-around;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.round {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 185px;
}

.match {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
  left: 100%;
  right: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.link:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  left: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container grid">
  <div class="round">
    <div class="round">
      <div class="match">test 1</div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="match">test 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="round">
      <div class="match">test 3</div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="match">test 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="round justify-space-around">
    <div class="match">test 1</div>
    <div class="link"></div>
    <div class="match">test 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
    <div class="match">test 1</div>
  </div>
```

And something I found [full responsive](https://codepen.io/jimmyhayek/pen/yJkdEB) :)

Comment: Look nice, I will ask if I can use grid ! As I said in comment bellow, I work on a service that will run on TV so I'm limited by modem technology and some are quite old !

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance but rather browser compatibility, [next examples](https://blog.codepen.io/2018/02/16/need-make-tournament-bracket/) ;)

Comment: Yes I know, but modem works as their own browser and they have their own compatibility :) Thanks for example, now I know the english term for what I'm looking for (tournament bracket) !